# Loading a font from the system in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a font called "pixelfont" that I would like to load onto my game. How can I load this font into pygame? I have tried the following method already:

```
    import pygame
    font_1_path = pygame.font.match_font("pixelfont", 0, 0)
    font_1 = pygame.font.Font(font_1_path, 128)
    text = font.render("Hello world!", True, (0, 0, 0))
    display.blit(text, [0, 0])
```

Why does this not print out "Hello world!" in pixelfont?

Comment: If your font, "pixelfont", is a ttf file, you can simply load it in with `pygame.font.Font("pixelfont.ttf", 128)` (assuming pixelfont.ttf is in the current working directory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pixelfont.ttf` instead of `pixelfont` if it is a `.ttf` file (font file) and it is in the same folder as your program. So use this instead after making sure the font file is in the same folder as your program:

```
font_1_path = pygame.font.match_font("pixelfont.ttf", 0, 0)
```